# Inflating a fragment in main activity brings an error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to be able to swap between two fragments in my main activity class. But when inflating the fragment my application crashes. Below is my code:

This is the XML code where my fragment will be placed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/rounded_dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for my Fragment

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.example.user.swim.AsyncTasks.GeoCodingTask;


    public class SearchLocation extends Fragment {
    private EditText destination;
    private Button search;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_locatiom,  null);

        search = view.findViewById(R.id.search_destination);
        destination = view.findViewById(R.id.destination);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        searchLocation(view);


        return view;
    }
```

Below is the code in my main activity to inflate the layout

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_place)!=null){


            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            SearchLocation fragment = new SearchLocation();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_place, fragment).commit();

        }
```

I get the following errors in my logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.swim, PID: 20462
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.swim/com.example.user.swim.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:617)
    at android.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:49)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3598)
    at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6182)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:783)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.user.swim.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This is the XML for fragment_search_locatiom

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/where_would_you_like_to_go"
        android:textAlignment="center" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:hint="Search for destination"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"

        android:textAlignment="textStart" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_destination" />



</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want to add the name/class attribute in the XML for the fragment because when you look at the official documentation adding those attributes won't make it possible to change fragments at runtime.

Also i've tried changing the MainActivity class to extend ActivityFragment but after more research i've discovered that ActivityFragment is a subclass of AppCompatActivity.

Comment: pase here your `fragment_search_locatiom` xml

Comment: i've added  the xml for fragment_search_location.
When i create the fragment using the name attribute it is displayed but if i do that i can't change the fragment on runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have copied your code and try to use it,when i use fragment in the SearchLocation it makes error so i changed it to Framlayout. 
Can't realy tell what is wrong in your code but this worked after i made changes
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_place) != null) {


            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            SearchLocation fragment = new SearchLocation();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_place, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
```

SearchLocation java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class SearchLocation extends Fragment {

    private EditText mSearch;
    private Button mDestination;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_location, null);

        mSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.search_destination);
        mDestination = view.findViewById(R.id.destination);
        mSearch.setText("Hello world");
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        /*searchLocation(view);*/

        return view;

    }
```

search_location xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchLocation">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_destination" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/destination" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Actually your solution works but i dont know why it works

Comment: happy i helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Framelayout` instead of `fragment` like the following

```
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: i've tried FrameLayout and still the same error
Also why would I use replace yet there is no previous fragment i'm replacing